# Print line and text of findstr

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with the following:

```
findstr "error" output > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
echo No errors found
) else (
echo Errors detected
)
```

However instead of "Errors detected" I'd like to learn how to print the line number and line text for every instance of a line with error. I have no idea how to begin to even do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Findstr` can display matching line numbers & the line itself with `/n`:

```
findstr /n "error" output 
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
echo No Errors detected
)
```